# Why does this equation hold true in this paper?

Tags: probability-theory

$$\large \log p(y|I,W)=\log \sum_l p(l|I,W)p(y|l,I,W)$$

In [this paper](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~xyang35/files/understanding-variational-lower.pdf#cite.ba2014multiple#page=3) on page 3. I don't know why it becomes a sum.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use just using that if you have a countable set $L$ then
$$
P(A|B)=\sum_{\ell \in L}P(\ell|B)P(A|\ell,B).
$$

Comment: Thanks very much! Any tutorials for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Bayesian Law:
$$p(y\mid l,I,W)=\frac{p(y,l,I,W)}{p(l,I,W)},\quad p(l\mid I,W)=\frac{p(l,I,W)}{p(I,W)}.$$
Then marginalise out $l$.